# JavaScript Map Function with React.js gives me index, but not value in the index

Tags: javascript, reactjs, map-function

So I have something like this in my React file, which works fine:

```
 {this.props.profile.first_name}
```

The above code would output the actual value in there: "John Doe" for example.

But, when I try and loop through each one to check to see if some profiles are empty (if the user never inputted a first name for example), I can't get the actually content to display. I get undefined or indexes. So the below code doesnt' help me.

```
     var props = Object.keys(this.props.profile).map(function(key, index, value) {

        console.log(key);  ### gives me index
        console.log(index);  ### undefined
        console.log(key[value]);  ### gives me data, but a label name, not the  
                                  actually value
        console.log(index[value]); ##undefined

        if ([key[value]) {
            return (
                <li className="list-group-item">
                    <label>{key}</label>{[value]}
                </li>
            );
        }

    })
```

How do I grab the actual data value in there, so that like this"{this.props.profile.first_name} the key or value checks agains the actual content in there (i.e. "John Doe") and not just an index or undefined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Object.keys` `returns` Array with `Object` keys, for example you have

```
this.props.profile = {
   first_name: 'name'
};
```

`Object.keys(this.props.profile)` returns `['first_name']`, in order to get value in map you should do

```
Object.keys(this.props.profile).map(function (key) {
  console.log(this.props.profile[key]);
}, this);
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/27812/)

Comment: thanks! worked great! and thanks for the jdfiddle example - that was really helpful